# How to "pip install" inside shell?

Tags: python, importerror

I forgot to `$ pip install sh` before starting `ipython`, but I feel the urge to import `bash` commands from [sh](https://pypi.org/project/sh/)

```
>>> from sh import tree
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sh
```

If I've just started then I can leave `ipython` and ask `bash`

```
$ python3 -m pip install sh
```

And carry on

```
>>> from sh import tree
>>> tree -d
```

But, if I have a lot of history inside `ipython` that I don't want to throw away, then how do I ask my current `python` `interpreter` to `pip install` a `package`?

Comment: `!pip install sh` should work. You can also open a shell in a new process and use pip from there.

Comment: Or, use `subprocess`

Comment: `pip`'s documentation answers this question [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program)